# What does Kuwait Airways allow in passenger's cabin besides a carry on?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage

https://www.kuwaitairways.com/en/is/free-carry-on-baggage

> In addition to the cabin hand luggage allowance, it is permitted to
> carry up to ONE additional item from the following: one ladies
> handbag, one briefcase, one coat, cape or blanket, one umbrella, one
> pair of binoculars or small camera, one pair of crutches or walking
> stick; or one duty free item purchased on day of flight.
>
> All passengers travelling by Kuwait Airways to the UK & USA (LHR &
> JFK) are requested to ensure that any electronics items
> (laptops/tablets/mobiles) being carried as hand luggage should be kept
> ON & out of its cover for security clearance checks.
>
> During the flight the above carry on items shall be kept in
> passenger’s own custody.
>
> Any additional items, other than those specified above, shall be
> weighed with the rest of the baggage and should the Cabin allowance be
> exceeded, it is subject to an excess baggage charge.

Besides a carry on suitcase, can a school-sized backpack of a laptop and some apples and snacks acceptable into Economy cabin?

Thanks.

Comment: How large is a "school sized backpack"?

Comment: I haven't measured it. I think it looks just like this one http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0281/2796/products/backpack-bike-train-cropped_1200x630.jpg

Comment: That seems to be a bit on the large side IMHO. You're at the mercy of gate agents.

Comment: @jcaron I always travel with a backpack similar to this plus a rollaboard, and have *never* been stopped. YMMV, but Kuwait Airways is a full service airline so I'd be very surprised if they give the OP any grief.

Comment: @lambshaanxy you've been lucky then. I know KLM for example has over the years become a LOT stricter because people were massively abusing the system and coming aboard carrying large shopping bags and trolleys as cabin luggage rather than pay for multiple pieces of hold luggage, resulting in angry passengers as the overhead bins would be full to capacity when less than half the passengers had boarded.

Answer (score 4):

I typically travel with a backpack (sized to fit a 14" laptop) and a small roll-aboard suitcase. The backpack has never been a problem and neither was the suitcase provided the fare did allow one (which many low-cost fares these days do not).

This being said, Kuwait's rules as written technically would not allow this so you may get flagged by a gate agent. Hard to tell upfront. Please also note that the total weight of your carry on is limited to 7kg which is VERY little. If you are travelling for more than just a couple of days, it's unlikely that 7kg will be enough for your stuff (since even most lightweight suitcases already weight about half of that empty). If you need to check luggage anyway, I would check all of it and just take the backpack in the cabin where you can either put it under the seat in front of you (uncomfortable for a long haul) or in the overhead (if you find space).

This all depends a lot on how strict the airline will enforce the rules. This can vary all over the place depending on mood of the day, recent airline policy, how full the flight is, etc.

My carry-on has definitely been weighed occasionally. Lufthansa group used to be very strict about this but has now eased up a bit. American carriers typically don't care. I don't know about Kuwait specifically.

Comment: Thanks. Is 7kg a limit on carry on only, not including backpack correct? What things would you bring that 7kg can include?

Comment: When my carry-on got weighed they only weighed the roll-aboard an not the backpack.  I don't know what Kuwait may do or not. You can bring whatever is legal as long as the total weight of the suitcase is less than 7kg. This is very little: your suitcase is likely to be fairly empty.